# Does my application need windows installer 3.1 as a prerequisite?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clickonce, windows-installer

...is there any way of checking such thing?

The default option as i remember was checked in my project, but it was long time agoooo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.

To check that, you can find that every .NET bootstrapper package contains **WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe** file (or similar file, for different versions of .NET), which is Windows Installer 3.1, to install it in case it's not available on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would need it if you are creating the setup project in VS2008.  Are you installing any other redistributable packages (i.e. .net 3.5) then it would be required as well.